# How to remove multiple highlight on main menu and have only first or one active?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WordPress page scroll to id plugin.
On load, the active menu item (anchor -- #id) are correctly highlighted.
But because the content of first section is small, the two fist section #about and #offers are highlighted.
This is the only css code of highlight effect that i add

```
.menu-item a.mPS2id-highlight {
   background-color:blue;
   color:white;
}
```

[image: this is]

The menu-item a id was added since wordpress menus (#apropos,#nosoffres...)

This is the name of the used plugin on wordpress : Page scroll to id

You can install and check the js code with me

thank for help

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to help you. Where is the JS? What is the markup of nav menu/page? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: No one is going to install a plugin to check the JS code. Since it's a plugin, reach out to the developer of the plugin for fix.